# cakephp line by line debugger?

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, debugging

Does anyone know of a debugging utility that can debug some cakephp code line by line?

I have a weird redirect bug in my `recipe` controller in my site. Accessing any action under the `recipe` controller while not logged in will redirect to the root of the site. I even made a new action with no code in it and it does the same thing.

```
class RecipeController extends AppController {
// ... stuff ....

    function test()
    {
    }
}
```

Everything redirects to users/login which in turn redirects to the home page.

I'm wonder if theres a line by line debugger so I can hunt down exactly what's doing the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, being redirected seems a normal behavior if you use authentication and you're not logged in. You can allow access to some actions without being logged in, like so,

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('test');
}
```

Comment: Oh so it is a default cakephp behavior, I see.

Answer (score 2):

You could install xdebug, then i debug line by line with netbeans but you can use also other tools...